# Updating a Heroku record with rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I realize this may not be "best practice" but this is sort of a temporary fix/experiment. I'm trying to update a record on Heroku using rails console but whenever I save it just rolls back.

```
UserAdmin = User.find_by(email: "User@example.com")
UserAdmin.admin = true
UserAdmin.save
```

The result is:

```
   (0.6ms)  BEGIN
   (0.6ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE (LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('User@example.com') AND "users"."id" != 3) LIMIT 1
  User Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE (LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('User@example.com') AND "users"."id" != 3) LIMIT 1
  User Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE (LOWER("users"."user_name") = LOWER('example') AND "users"."id" != 3) LIMIT 1
  User Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE (LOWER("users"."user_name") = LOWER('example') AND "users"."id" != 3) LIMIT 1
   (0.4ms)  ROLLBACK
   (0.4ms)  ROLLBACK
```

Am I going about this wrong? Is there any particular reason the record is not saving on Heroku?

Comment: Something is screwy. Either you have bad data in your table or your validations are messed up. Add the model and try looking at the data in the table by doing `User.where(email: "User@example.com").count` to see if you have duplicates. Also your naming is very wrong - identifiers that start with an uppercase letter are constants in ruby so unless you are naming a class stick to `snake_case`.

Comment: Try it with `UserAdmin.save!` (the bang will raise an exception) and see what validation errors, if any, you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you get if you do:

```
  user_admin = User.find_by(email: "User@example.com")
  user_admin.admin = true
  user_admin.valid?
  user_admin.errors.full_messages
```

(I realize this is not an answer yet, but posted it this way because it would be too messy as a comment.)

Comment: This gave me what I needed, although not technically an answer I figured it out.  Turns out in order to save I had to provide the record's password, I'm not sure if that's a Heroku thing or because I have a password_digest but a password was needed.